# $L_{1,1,1}(v)=\langle (1,1,1),v \rangle$ in $\mathbb{R}^3$

Tags: linear-algebra

There is a doubt that came to my mind.

If I have the Euclidean inner product on $\mathbb{R}^3$ over the field of scalars K=\mathbb{R}. There is the following equality : $\dim V=\dim Im+\dim \ker$ given V is arbitrary vector space and $Im$ stands for its image given a linear transformation $T$.

If I define the following linear functional on $\mathbb{R}^3$ to be $L_{1,1,1}(v)=\langle (1,1,1),v \rangle$ in which v stands for all vectors in $\mathbb{R}^3$.

If I apply $\dim V=\dim Im+\dim \ker$, I know $\dim Im=\dim\mathbb{R}=1$ and $\dim\mathbb{R}^3$ then I know $\dim\ker=\dim V-\dim Im=3-1=2$

If I pick the vector $(2,-1,-1)\in\mathbb{R}^3$, then $L_{1,1,1}(v)=\langle (1,1,1),2,-1,-1 \rangle=2-1-1=0$, however (2,-1,-1) does not belong to the kernel once $\dim\ker=2$, which is a contradiction.

**Questions**:
 Why does $\dim V=\dim Im+\dim \ker$ does not seem to be working on this case? What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $L_{(1,1,1)}(2,-1,-1) = 0$ then $(2,-1,-1) \in \ker L_{(1,1,0)}$, why do you think it is not? The kernel of $L_{(1,1,1)}$ consists of the vectors orthogonal do $(1,1,1)$, so geometrically it is the plane in $\Bbb R^3$ passing through the origin, with normal $(1,1,1)$. And this has dimension $2$. There's no contradiction whatsoever.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! But $\ker L_{(1,1,1)}=2$ but (2,-1,-1) cannot be generated by a basis of dimension two, right?

Comment: So how can it belong to the $\ker L_{(1,1,1)}$?

Comment: First of all, write thing nicely, $\dim \ker L_{(1,1,1)} = 2$, and not $\ker L_{(1,1,1)} = 2$, this last does not make sense. You're confusing elements of the subspace with the subspace itself. One possible basis for $\ker L_{(1,1,1)}$ is $\{ (2,-1,-1), (1,1,1)\times (2,-1,-1)  \}$ (think analytic geometry).

Comment: It belongs in $\ker L_{(1,1,1)}$ because $L_{(1,1,1)}(2,-1,-1) = 0$, period.

Comment: And it is a combination of that basis I wrote, no problem: $$(2,-1,-1) = \color{red}{1} \cdot (2,-1,-1) + \color{red}{0} \cdot (2,-1,-1)\times(1,1,1).$$

Comment: So why do we talk about Kernel dimensions if three dimension vector space can belong to a two dimensional space?

Comment: $(2,-1,-1) = \color{red}{1} \cdot (2,-1,-1) + \color{red}{0} \cdot (2,-1,-1)\times(1,1,1)$ is a three dimensional basis right?

Comment: 1) The kernel is a subspace, hence it has a dimension. The quantity of components of a vector has little to do with the dimension of any subspace that vector belong to - this becomes clear when you think of vector spaces other than $\Bbb R^n$. 

2) Any basis for $\ker L_{(1,1,1)}$ consists of **two** vectors only. Again, the quantity of vectors has little to do with the fact that each vector consists of three numbers.

Comment: Now I do not know what dimension is for... Does it not mean the number of vectors? If you have 3 number it must consist of three vectors right?

Comment: I guess it is better to take a course in linear algebra then to see all the relevant definitions in a organized way... The dimension of a vector space is the number of elements in one (hence in any) basis of the space. A basis is a collection $\mathcal{B} \subseteq V$ that is linearly independent and spans $V$.

To break that wrong intuition: $$W = \{ (x,y,x+2y) \in \Bbb R^3 \mid x,y \in \Bbb R \}$$ is a subspace of dimension **two**, despite its elements having three components. One basis is $\{(1,0,1); (0,1,2)\}$.

Comment: I have read an introductory book on linear algebra and now I am reading Serge Lang Linear Algebra, I am going through dual spaces. I have never been presented with that notion of basis as yours.

Comment: The books have never dwelled to much on the basis. They emphasised more the construction and understanding of the orthogonal basis.

Comment: This is **so** strange that I can't even. The concepts of basis and dimension are usually one of the first things that appear in linear algebra, and most certainly they come before dual spaces and inner products. Take a book like [Blyth and Robertson's](http://www.springer.com/gb/book/9781852336622), don't skip anything, and you can't go wrong.